# Python data type discovery

Tags: python, types

I have a function that receives a str, that can represent any of the following:

```
float <-- eg: '1.5', '1.0'
int <-- eg: '123','0'
datetime.date <-- eg: if so, it'll always be in this format '30-AUG-18'
str <-- eg: "value1", "01", "02"
NoneType <-- eg: None
```

How can I gracefully discover and then cast the input to its appropriate type?

Comment: You can use a bunch of if statements: `if isinstance(x, float)`

Comment: btw `int('01') == 1`

Comment: Yes this 01 is tricky, i want '01', '02' to remain strs, but 1 or 2 should be int.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's typecasting to achieve this:

```
float('2.3')
int('2')
datetime.strptime('2018-02-02', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
from ast import literal_eval
from datetime import datetime

def dataType(s):
    s = s.strip()
    try:
        t = literal_eval(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return 'datetime.date', datetime.strptime(s.upper(), '%d-%b-%y')
        except ValueError:
            return 'str', s
    except SyntaxError:
        return 'str', s
    else:
        return type(t).__name__, t

for s in ['1.5', '1.0', '123', '0', '30-AUG-18', 'value1', '01', '02', 'None']:
    type_name, value = dataType(s)
    print(type_name, str(value))
```

Outputs:

> ```
> float 1.5
> float 1.0
> int 123
> int 0
> datetime.date 2018-08-30 00:00:00
> str value1
> str 01
> str 02
> NoneType None
> ```

Comment: I also want '1.0' to be 1, ie, if return integer whenever i can without losing precision.